# Arrays - summing neighbours of elements?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

The question asks to write static method sumNeighbours which takes an array of integers as an argument and returns an array with the same number of elements as the original array such that each integer in the new array is the sum of its neighbours and itself in the original array.

e.g.

```
[10, 20, 30, 40]
```

will be

```
[30, 60, 90, 70]
30(10+20) 60(20+10+30) 90(30+20+40) 70(40+30)
```

Thanks. Here's the code I've done and it works, BUT only for SOME cases, not ALL. Can anyone recommend a more efficient way to approach this? Without hard-coding all those if's and else's for certain cases.

```
public static int[] sumNeighbours(int[] values) {
int[] list = new int[values.length];
for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    if (values.length > 1) {
        if (values[i] == values[0]) {
            list[i] = values[i] + values[i+1];
        }
        else if (values[i] == values[values.length-1]) {
            list[i] = values[i] + values[i-1];
        }
        else {
            list[i] = values[i] + values[i-1] + values[i+1];
        }
    }
    else {
        list [i] = values[i];
    }
}
return list;
}
```

Comment: what's the logic for output `[30, 60, 90, 70]` ?

Comment: please provide code that you have tried and format it correctly in your post.

Comment: Sorry about that! I've edited in more fuller detail!

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Provide a failing examples. Beyond that, take this as opportunity to learn how to use a debugger or how to use trace print statements to understand what your code is doing!

Comment: A note about your code, you shouldn’t be using the values at the index to determine your location (as the values can be the same even when the indices are not)

Answer (score 0):

First: your input may be null, so null check first and I guess return null in that case.

Second: after creating an array of the same size you need to iterate the input and for each index check two things:

1. If index is smaller than (length-1) add the element on the right
2. If the index is greater than 0 add the element on the left
3. Always add the element in the current index

Done?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use values to check if the element is either first of last, use the indexes and also have a nullptr check. Your code will fail for cases like `[30,30,30]`

```java
    public static int[] sumNeighbours(int[] values) {
        if (null == values)
            return null;
        int[] list = new int[values.length];
        for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
            if (values.length > 1) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    list[i] = values[i] + values[i+1];
                }
                else if (i == values.length-1) {
                    list[i] = values[i] + values[i-1];
                }
                else {
                    list[i] = values[i] + values[i-1] + values[i+1];
                }
            }
            else {
                list [i] = values[i];
            }
        }
        return list;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here's the code I've done and it works, BUT only for SOME cases, not ALL

Probably it's because you compare values rather than indices: `if (values[i] == values[0])` must be `if (i == 0)` and `if (values[i] == values[values.length-1])` must be `if (i == values.length - 1)`.

And snippet with less code and null-check may looks as follows

```
public static int[] sumNeighbours(int[] input) {
    if (input == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int[] result = new int[input.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        int sum = input[i];

        if (i > 0) {
            sum += input[i - 1];
        }
        if (i < (input.length - 1)) {
            sum += input[i + 1];
        }

        result[i] = sum;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More efficiency way if you remove your if blocks within your loop:

```
public static int[] sumNeighbours(final int[] values) {

    if (null == values || 2 > values.length) {
        return values;
    }

    final int len = values.length;
    final int[] list = new int[len];

    list[0] = values[0] + values[1];
    list[len - 1] = values[len - 2] + values[len - 1];

    for (int i = 1; i < len - 2; i++) {
        list[i] = values[i - 1] + values[i] + values[i + 1];
    }

    return list;
}
```

You do not need summary 3 numbers on the edges.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Out,

```
public static int[] sumNeighbours(int[] values) {
int[] list = new int[(values.length)];
for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
 if (values.length > 1) { //To Check if there are more than one values
    if(i==0) //It will check if it is first element
    {
        list[i]=values[i]+values[i+1]; //Add First value and second value to place it in first location. As first location has only one Neighbor 

    }
    else if (i==(values.length-1)) //TO check If its last value
    {
        list[i]=values[i]+values[i-1]; //As Last Location has only one Neighbor
    }
    else
    {
         list[i]=values[i]+values[i-1]+values[i+1]; //For All intermediate locations
  }
}
}
return list;
}
```